# Python Service - Wix MSI Installer - Auto Start on bootup not working

Tags: python, wcf, service, wix, windows-installer

I have a working python win32 service, trying to distribute it through msi, built with WiX Toolset.

However, the service gets installed as "Startup Type Automatic", starts when installing, starts with `sc` commands, and functions properly.

But when rebooting the computer, it doesnt start automatically. It tries to start, but I get 2 errors in the Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> System

`A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Edit Service service to connect.`

`The Edit Service service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`

Here is the WiX section that references serviceinstall.

```
             <File Id="MainEXE" Source="editservice.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
                    <ServiceControl Id="Edit" Name=Edit Service" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />


                    <ServiceInstall 
                        Id="service" 
                        Account="\Ps" 
                        Password="scrubed$" 
                    Start="auto" 
                    ErrorControl="normal" 
                    Name="Edit Service" 
                    Type="ownProcess" 
                    Vital="yes"      />

                    <RemoveFolder Id="Purge"  On="uninstall" />
```

Any ideas why this would fail to be started ONLY when system starts up? I can supply further WiX or the python service implemenation if needed

Comment: Does it depend on another service that hasn't come up yet? BTW, you may want to scrub that password in the example...

Comment: Thanks, I had scrubbed it, and overwrote with a copy and paste... D'oh..

There is no depedency, I think I am having an issue with "auto" during boottime, if the network is not yet loaded up, NYDPS domain may not be properly accessible, I am testing with a delayed start

Comment: However, this is regression from some earlier changes, which confuses me as to why `auto` previously worked and now only `deferred` will work.. I had undergone a decoupling exercise and my services now imports multiple custom modules as opposed to none. I use py2exe to bundle it up but it shouldn't  be any different from 1 file

Comment: "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." is not an install problem, to state the obvious. The service is being slow or failing in its start logic, it's taking too long. Debug the service, not the install!

Comment: @PhilDW agreed, but the service works fine If I start it manually, it starts right up in a second, I had assumed it was the way I was distributing it... in my opinion if the service failed to start on bootup, it should have failed to start elsewhere if it was issue in service

Comment: It looks like a dependency issue, it really does. It requires something at boot time that is already running when you start it manually.

Comment: it seems as if my newest answer did noot even fix the issue I had jumped the gun. I wonder if it is due to a circular import, or py2exe. I'll figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tdelaney @PhilDW THE REAL ANSWER..

FWIW - using `time.sleep()` within a python service, is to enter an infinite loop which takes processor time. Receiving singles within an infinite loop, is not possible. There is a **windows service implementation** way to accomplish the sleep

instead of

`sleep.time(10)`

use

`#where timeout = sleep time`

`if win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, timeout) == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    break`

**NOTE** - sleep.time input is in seconds, `win32event.WaitForSingleObject` is in ms

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out.. **every single line** in the service start function gets executed.

**However** - The last line of code is a call to `time.sleep(10)` . It seems as if this line of code does not finish running, resulting in a failed start **even though the service is running**.

In production, the sleep time will be risen to an hour. Because of this I think a **deferred start** is the preferred method.

In order to do this in WiX Follow the below code template.

```
                 <ServiceControl Id="Edit" Name="NBC Edit Service" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />


                    <ServiceInstall 
                        Id="service" 
                        Account="NYDPS\Portus" 
                        Password="getyourownpassword" 
                        Start="auto"
                        ErrorControl="normal"
                        Name="NBC Edit Service"
                        Type="ownProcess"
                        Vital="yes" >

                        <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall ="yes" />
                    </ServiceInstall>

                    <RemoveFolder Id="Purge"  On="uninstall" />
```